# Return undefined on Array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I don't want this map to return undefined how can i do that ?

```
var onCompareSelectedClick = function () {
            var talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources = appliedResourcesEntries.map(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                if(res.compareSelected == true) {
                    return data.getTalentProfileInfo(res.RES.RES_ID);
                }
            });
            console.log(talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources);
            this.openCompareTPDlg(talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources);
        }.bind(this);
```

Comment: It looks like the problem might be the conditional inside the msp statement, but you should really get a fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Wow it return undefind when res.compareSelected = false..i don't think it's needed more info

Answer (score 0):

Just add `else` statement inside `map` method returning needed value, like:

```
if(res.compareSelected == true) {
   return data.getTalentProfileInfo(res.RES.RES_ID);
} else {
   return 'default_value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Use the Array.filter method after Array.map to remove undefined elements in the new array.

---

Expanding on @Bloomca's answer:

[As stated in the documentation provided here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Hence the reason why your new array contains undefined elements is because you are not explicitly calling return within the function on some elements that are called using the provided function. In Javascript, not explicitly calling return will nevertheless return `undefined`.

For example, in the following method newArray will be set to the logged result:

`[ undefined, 2, 3 ]`

```
newArray = [1,2,3].map(function(elem) { if (elem > 1) return elem })
console.log(newArray)
```

This is why the answer provided above will no longer result in `undefined` elements within the new array. The conditional will resolve if the condition `res.compareSelected == true` is not true to the return statement within the else block (note that you could simply remove the `true` here and simply put `res.compareSelected` which would be better practice).

Based on your question you may find using the `Array.filter` method to return an `Array` without the undefined values. And with only the values on which you have called the function `data.getTalentProfileInfo(res.RES.RES_ID)`.

You could do this in the following manner:

```
var onCompareSelectedClick = function () {
    var arr = appliedResourcesEntries.map(function(res) {
        if(res.compareSelected == true) {
            return data.getTalentProfileInfo(res.RES.RES_ID);
        }
    });
    var talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources = arr.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem;
    });
console.log(talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources);
this.openCompareTPDlg(talentProfileInfoForAppliedResources);
}.bind(this);
```

[You can read about the Array.filter method here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)